# Prevent Sub-menu from collapsing after clicking on link (Bootstrap 3.1.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap menu is as follows (this is the code snippet for one menu-item out of many):

```
<!-- Code for Navigable menu (mobile) -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container commonWidth">

    <button type="button" style="width: 100%" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#led-collapse">
        LED & Lighting <b class="caret"></b>
    </button>

    <!-- Collect the nav links for toggling -->                        
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse hidden-sm" id="led-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="dropdown visible-xs">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">LED Lights<b class="caret visible-xs"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">LED Lamps & Tubes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Downlights, Spotlights & COB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LED Panels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LED Surface</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Commercial & Industrial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LED GU10 Fittings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LED Strips</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown visible-xs">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Luminaires (Fittings)<b class="caret visible-xs"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Domestic Tube Fittings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Floodlights</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </div>   <!-- End LED Menu -->
    </div> <!-- End commonWidth -->        
</nav>
```

The issue is that immediately after clicking a 3rd level link (.dropdown-menu > li > a), entire 2nd level menu (li class="dropdown visible-xs") collapses. However, I want this to stay open after the 3rd level link is clicked. 
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dk49/ugzwmhm6/
Any Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: can you reproduce the same in a fiddle?

Comment: Here is the fiddle (play with grey coloured menu - Fans, LED, etc. For eg. click on Fans -> Ceiling Fans -> Economy. After clicking economy link, the Ceiling Fans block collapses, but I want it to stay open): http://jsfiddle.net/dk49/ugzwmhm6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the `economy` link is clicked the `click event` is getting propagated to its parent, from there it goes to the next parent and so on . when it reaches the third parent, the third parent element is reacting to it by toggling the open class. So if you stop the propagation it will stay as it is. 
Try the code below.

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

This code will stop the propagation of the `anchor` tag to its parent

In case if you want to prevent the default click action use

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e){
    if($(this).attr('href') == "#" || $(this).attr('href') == "") // New code
        e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

**Update**

I have updated the code to prevent scrolling if the URL is `#` or if there is no URL. this should serve the purpose

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer..it works! However, I am now facing one more issue. On using stopPropagation() method, the view jumps to top of page after clicking economy (or any other third level link). Is there a way to stop this scrolling? Using preventDefault() solves it but I cant use it as I cant disable the URL.

Comment: hey there, i was trying to do the same thing but its not working what i see is when i click on the sub menu a class "collapse" gets added to the nav and it gets close again. This is the code for button https://jsfiddle.net/uohgds1f/